# What is the Rails 3 Way to do a basic AR find on one object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is it:

```
u = User.find_by_email("me@myplace.com")
```

or:

```
u = User.where(:email => "me@myplace.com").first
```

I think I read that conditions are being phased out in 3.1.

I know you want to stick with AREL on retrieving multiple objects, because it figures out when to actually do the query (like if you're iterating through a collection). But I don't know what the convention is for grabbing singles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use both interchangeably.

I haven't read anything about the `find_by` methods being deprecated, but if your concern is that they will be, then use the second approach. You're only other option is to call `last`. You could also call `all` but that would return the object in an array.

Read section [1.1 Retrieving a Single Object](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object) of the Edge Guides article Active Record Querying for more information.

Comment: Thanks John, the Edge Guides will come in handy. I hadn't been reading those.

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help! Be sure to keep the Edge Guides bookmarked -- it is an invaluable resource.